# Producing .obj files from Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, language-translation

Please tell me how you persuade Delphi 10.1.2 (Berlin) to produce, not just .lib files, but also the .obj files. I need to add some of my components to the C++ version of Berlin. I've successfully installed the components but it won't compile a project using them because it can't find the .obj files. I've set the project option and the .lib are produced, but no .obj files. Do I need to use dcc32.exe to produce them? Or am I missing something simple?

Comment: Did you add the the .pas files of your components to your C++Builder project? That should be enough to let C++Builder make the Delphi compiler produce the required .obj and header files and whatever else you need.

Comment: I added the directory my .pas files are in to the library and browsing paths. I have managed to install an earlier version of the components into my Rad Studio XE, which has both Delphi and C++. However the copy of Berlin C++ is not mine, it belongs to my customer, and I only have Berlin Delphi. So I have to port the components between machines.

Comment: Ah, OK, then you will have to do what the answer says.

Answer (score 4):

Find the menu :

> Project -> Options ->

In there you can select, from the `Output - C/C++` section of the Delphi Compiler options the C/C++ output file generation options.
[image: object file option]

From the documentation : [Package Files Created By Compiling](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Package_Files_Created_by_Compiling)

If you are using DCC32 [on the command line](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DCC32.EXE,_the_Delphi_Command_Line_Compiler), use the `-JPHNE` switch.

Comment: When I view that line on my version of Delphi (professional) I don't see all those options. I only see "Generate all C++Builder files (including package libs) ". Are you using the same version as me? Or do I need to tick another option?

Comment: Many thanks. I now realize that I need the full version of Rad Studio, with both personalities to produce the required files. I'll have to speak nicely to finance, and hope they let me buy it!

Comment: @Maroc I'm also using D10 Professional, no C++ personality.  This screenshot is from Seattle, but I don't think these options have changed with Berlin...[the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Output_-_C/C%2B%2B), at least, seems to be the same.  These `.obj` files are produced by dcc32(the Delphi compiler), not bcc32(the C++ compiler).

Comment: @Maroc This is a dropdown menu, in case you missed that?  You have to click the arrow at the right.

Comment: Interesting! I've tried XE, XE4, Berlin, and Tokyo, all allow that drop down when I load a normal .exe package, but not when I load my EoParserSuite design time package. I've been using Delphi since its first release, and thought I understood it a little, and yet it can still surprise me. If anyone can suggest a reason why the options from the drop down is stopped when compiling my BPL project, I would love to know. The package was first written under Rad Studio 2006  and has been translated to most Delphi versions since then.

Comment: @Maroc Wow... five years later.  I must have missed that last comment.  Anyway, : [Note: For Delphi packages, only the last choice is offered.](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/C%2B%2B_Object_File_(*.obj,_*.o))